# Feedback linearize of ODE-system and transient processes of all variables

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

We have the following nonlinear system of ODE:

\begin{cases} x'=-2(x-1)+u \\ y'=\frac{d}{dt}(-2(x-1))+(-2(x-1)) \end{cases}

I tried to do feedback linearization for variable $y$. Here is my code.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {xs = -1, xe = 1}

f = -(x[t] - xe)^2

asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x'[t] == D[f, x[t]] + u[t], 
   y'[t] == D[D[f, x[t]], t] + D[f, x[t]]}, {x[t], y[t]}, 
  u[t], {y[t]}, t]

\[ScriptCapitalF] = FeedbackLinearize[asys, {{z1, z2}, v}]

\[ScriptCapitalF]["LinearSystem"]

StateFeedbackGains[%, {-1, -1}]

\[ScriptCapitalF][{"ClosedLoopSystem", %}]

Plot[Evaluate@OutputResponse[{%, {xs, 1}}, 0, {t, 0, 10}], {t, 0, 10},
  PlotRange -> All]
```

**Question:**  How to see the output by variable $x$?